# Shows rows with different values for single ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a (part of a) table that looks like this:

```
Some_ID     Some_Value
1           A
2           B
3           C
3           C
3           D
4           E
4           E
4           E
```

I want to find all rows that has different values per ID, so for this example my output should be:

```
Some_ID     Some_Value
3           C
3           C
3           D
```

It doesn't even have to look like this, it would also be enough to just get the IDs without the values.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you mean by diffenent values per ID?

Comment: You want to get ID's that have multiple values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT some_id
FROM table_name
GROUP BY some_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT some_value) > 1
ORDER BY some_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.

Comment: @jarlh How I said, just the IDs are enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-query that returns Some_ID's having more than 1 different Some_Value. JOIN with that result:

```
select t1.Some_ID, t1.Some_Value
from tablename t1
join (select Some_ID
      from tablename
      group by Some_ID
      having count(distinct Some_Value) > 1) t2
   on t1.Some_ID = t2.Some_ID
```